# T-SQL - update all rows even if repeating data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working with T-SQL.  I have two tables: fullname and SSN table.  SSN table has 10000+ records with a first name, last name, and ssn column.  fullname table has 100 records with first name and last name .

I want to update SSN table with the first name and last name records from fullname.  At the end of the 100 records, I just want to repeat the names(start from row 1 of fullname) until it finishes updating all records in SSN table.  I attempted a MERGE like this below but got a 'The MERGE statement attempted to UPDATE or DELETE the same row more than once' error message.  In this code below, I was trying to update [last name] column first. Can you help please?  Thanks.

```
MERGE INTO [SSN]
   USING [fullname]
      ON 1=1
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE
        SET [last name] = [fullname].[last name];
```

Comment: So to clarify:  (1) You don't care about WHICH name is assigned to WHICH ssn, but you want to use a rotation of the 100 names rather than just using a single name, right?  (2) Do the tables have sequential ID columns?

Comment: (1) No, it doesn't matter.  There is no name matching with SSN.  This will be all test data.  (2) Only SSN does have sequential id columns but I can add sequential ID to fullname table if needed.

Comment: Please tell me you are not storing the SSN in clear text. I realize you are generating test data but SSN needs to be encrypted at all times.

Comment: Why are you using MERGE here instead of an update?

Comment: @Sean, these are test SSNs, not real SSNs at all.  This is a test database solely in-house. What information I'm storing is irrelevant.  My overall goal is to update all 10000+ records with the first name last name.  About your second question, yes I can use UPDATE but can you suggest how please?  I tried UPDATE also but it would only update up to 100 records.

Comment: See my posted answer. I realize what you are storing isn't relevant for the question but storing SSN in plain text is a horrible practice that is actually illegal in many states.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE** - corrections and explanations

If both tables have sequential ids, then you can change your `ON` clause to

```
ON [fullname].[ID] = [SSN].[ID] % 100
```

The idea is, for every `[SSN].[ID]` you need to pick exactly one `[fullname].[ID]`, and the `%` (integer division remainder, or modulo) operator gives us one way to do this, picking each `[fullname]` record roughly the same number of times.

```
fullname 0 matches SSN 0, 100, 200, 300, ...
fullname 1 matches SSN 1, 101, 201, 301, ...
```

For it to work without leaving any gaps, you need `[fullname]` records with every `[ID]` value from 0 to 99.  If the first `[ID]` is 1, you can adjust this to say

```
ON [fullname].[ID] = ([SSN].[ID] % 100) + 1
```

assuming you have a `[fullname]` record with `[ID]` of 100.  If you have a different number of total `[fullname]` records, you could change the number after the `%`.

Comment: If it's a problem to add a missing ID, you *might* be able to fake it with `row_number() over()`; but I'm skeptical (and not in a position to run tests right now)

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this but will it update all 10000+ rows?

Comment: Glad to hear it worked; sorry I didn't get back to your first comment question, I'll add a little clarification to the answer to explain why this should work

Comment: Proofreading it, btw, I'm surprised it worked; it looks like I wrote it wrong originally...

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with an update statement along these lines. This assumes there are no gaps in ssnTable.RowNumber (or whatever your actual name is). If you have gaps it is a pretty easy step to utilize RowNumber there too.

```
update s
set LastName = fn.FullName
from ssnTable s
join 
(
    select ROW_NUMBER() over(order by LastName) as RowNum
        , LastName
    from FullName
) fn on fn.RowNum = s.RowNumber % 100
```